# Python: extracting data values from one file with IDs from a second file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I’m new to coding, and trying to extract a subset of data from a large file. 
File_1 contains the data in two columns: `ID` and `Values`.
File_2 contains a large list of IDs, some of which may be present in File_1 while others will not be present. 
If an ID from File_2 is present in File_1, I would like to extract those values and write the ID and value to a new file, but I’m not sure how to do this. Here is an example of the files:

---

File_1: data.csv

```
ID                                 Values
HOT224_1_0025m_c100047_1            16
HOT224_1_0025m_c10004_1              3
HOT224_1_0025m_c100061_1             1
HOT224_1_0025m_c10010_2              1
HOT224_1_0025m_c10020_1              1
```

File_2: ID.xlsx

```
IDs
HOT224_1_0025m_c100047_1
HOT224_1_0025m_c100061_1
HOT225_1_0025m_c100547_1
HOT225_1_0025m_c100561_1
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col = 0)
ID_file = pd.read_excel('ID.xlsx')
values_from_ID = data_file.loc[['ID_file']]
```

The following error occurs:

```
KeyError: "None of [['ID_file']] are in the [index]"
```

Not sure if I am reading in the excel file correctly.
I also do not know how to write the extracted data to a new file once I get the code to do it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True)
ID_file = pd.read_excel('ID.xlsx', index_col=0)
res = data_file.loc[ID_file.index].dropna()
res.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Content of `result.csv`:

```
IDs,Values
HOT224_1_0025m_c100047_1,16.0
HOT224_1_0025m_c100061_1,1.0
```

### In steps:

You need to read your csv with whitespace delimited:

```
data_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True)
```

it looks like this:

```
>>> data_file
                          Values
ID                              
HOT224_1_0025m_c100047_1      16
HOT224_1_0025m_c10004_1        3
HOT224_1_0025m_c100061_1       1
HOT224_1_0025m_c10010_2        1
HOT224_1_0025m_c10020_1        1
```

Now, read your Excel file, using the ids as index:

```
ID_file = pd.read_excel('ID.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

and you use its index with `loc`to get the matching entries from your first dataframe. Drop the missing values with `dropna()`:

```
res = data_file.loc[ID_file.index].dropna()
```

Finally, write to the result csv:

```
res.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: This worked with a slight adjustment. I did not need to read the csv with white-space delimited.

Comment: Your csv is comma delimited? BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, the csv is comma delimited. I realize that was not obvious due to how I posted the information  from the csv file. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple dictionary in Python. You can make a dictionary from file 1 and read the IDs from File 2. The IDS from file 2 can be checked in the dictionary and only the matching ones can be written to your output file. Something like this could work :

```
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
#Skip the CSV Header
lines = lines[1:] 
table = {l.split()[0]:l.split()[1] for l in lines if len(l.strip()) != 0}

with open('id.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
#Skip the CSV Header
lines = lines[1:]

matchedIDs = [(l.strip(),table[l.strip()]) for l in line if l.strip() in table]
```

Now you will have your matched IDs and their values in a list of tuples called `matchedIDs`. You can write them in any format you like in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to python programming. So the code that I used below might not be the most efficient. The situation I assumed is that find ids in data.csv also in id.csv, there might be some ids in data.csv not in id.csv and vise versa.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
id2 = pd.read_csv('id.csv')
data.ID = data['ID']
id2.ID = idd['IDs']
d=[]
for row in data.ID:
    d.append(row)
f=[]
for row in id2.ID:
    f.append(row)
g=[]
for i in d:
    if i in f:
        g.append(i)
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col='ID')
new_data = data.loc[g,:]
new_data.to_csv('new_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using. It worked perfectly. Thanks to everyone for their responses.

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
ID_file = pd.read_excel('ID.xlsx', index_col=0)
res = data_file.loc[ID_file.index].dropna()
res.to_csv('result.csv')
```